# Calculating frequency interval for tasks

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

I have a cron job that gets results from the DB to check it the interval set by user falls on today's date. I am currently thinking of doing it as below :

1. Get the time column for the row. Ex:2017-05-25 00:00:00
2. Get the frequency set. Ex:Every 2 weeks.
3. Get the current date in above format. Ex:2017-05-31 00:00:00
4. Get the difference in days. Ex:6 days.
5. Convert the frequency set to days. Ex:2 weeks = 14 days;
6. Divide (difference in time(days)) by (frequency in days). Ex:6/14

This way I will only get the result to be true when 2 weeks have passed since the time set. I.e., 14/14, 28/14, 42/14,...

If the frequency is in months, I can start dividing by 30. But somehow this feels like a hacky way of doing it. So my question is if there is better way of doing this calculation to check the difference.

This is what I have done as explained by above example.

```
` $frequency = ; // Get the relevant fields from db
  $today = date(Y-m-d H:i:s);
     foreach ($frequency as $key => $value) {
       $frequency_in_days;
       $frequency_type = $value->type;
       $frequency_repeat = $value->repeat;

       if($frequency_type == 1){
         $frequency_in_days = $frequency_repeat;
       } elseif($frequency_type == 2) {
         $frequency_in_days = $frequency_repeat * 7;
       } elseif($frequency_type == 3) {
         $frequency_in_days = $frequency_repeat * 30;
       } elseif($frequency_type == 4) {
         $frequency_in_days = $frequency_repeat * 365;
       }

      //  Get number of days spent between start_date and today in days.
       $interval = date_diff($value->start_date, $today)->format('%a');
       $result = $interval % $frequency_in_days;

       if ($result == 0) {
        //  Frequency falls today! Do the job.
       }
     }`
```

Note: The cron job runs this script. The script again needs to check if the today falls under the frequency set.

Also for argument's sake, is this the best logic to calculate the difference?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any code? The format of the rows int the recordset? What is the date in the first point? the last event occurred?
I think you should reword your question a bit to make it clearer, and less closure prone. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added code. I didn't add any code before because I thought the problem statement was explanation enough. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I removed my question because `this db has thousands of records` while in original question you loop through records

Comment: If you want to do this using mysql, mysql has this functionality built in see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
Table "schedule" 
`last_run` timestamp, 
`frequency_seconds` int
```

example query for tasks that should go every two weeks:

```
SELECT *
FROM schedule
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(last_run, NOW()) >= frequency_seconds
```

after fetching rows update  `last_run` to `NOW()`